# How do I shave down a sidewalk?

Tags: concrete, sidewalk

I have a sidewalk where one of the sections that was repaired by a previous homeowner is raised up above the surrounding sections.  I've seen some sites on the internet talking about shaving down the sidewalk rather than breaking it up and replacing it.  Is this something I can do myself?  If so, how?

[image: Sidewalk view 1]

[image: Sidewalk view 2]

Comment: Looking at the flaky condition of the concrete patch and the fact that it is such a small section I'd say the investing time and money in any type of grinding process is a total waste of money. Break it up, re-form and then pour a new section.

Comment: If you do grind it, make sure you wear a proper face mask. Concrete dust is nasty stuff.

Comment: @MichaelKaras seems like that is the way to go - if you make that an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the flaky condition of the concrete patch and the fact that it is such a small section I'd say the investing time and money in any type of grinding process is a total waste of money.

The open voids in the surface of the concrete and the grainy texture of the patch area really indicates the low grade of the installed lump.

Break it up, re-form and then pour a new section.

I wouldn't be surprised if you find it very easy to break this up.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a small space, too. You might be able to take it apart with a sledgehammer in an hour or two.

Answer (score 1):

Rent  terrazzo grinder, perhaps - or just go into the tool rental place near you and explain your problem and ask what they have that might work. Something generally LIKE a terrazzo floor grinder (but perhaps more suited to use outside) would be more or less right. Breaking it up and re-pouring it might be quicker, cheaper and easier.